# Is .Net Framework 4.8 compatible with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.8

I am looking to see if there are any official mentions about .NET Framework 4.8 being compatible with Visual Studio 2017.

I can see that there is backwards compatibility between applications built with .Net Framework 4.8 to 4.5 as noted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility#backward-compatibility) but on the other side, looking at [Visual Studio 2017 Support for .NET Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs#-visual-studio-2017-support-for-net-development) I don't see 4.8 being mentioned.

Installing it locally and checking, it looks like .Net Framework 4.8 is compatible to Visual Studio 2017, but I am still looking for a more official resource confirming that it is safe to use them together for development.

[image: .NET Framework 4.8 available in Visual Studio 2017]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's compatible.

Visual Studio 2017 was released before .NET Framework 4.8, so it makes sense that the original documentation of Visual Studio 2017 does not mention .NET Framework 4.8. In particular, the document you linked to mentions "05/31/2018" as its modification date, which is also before .NET Framework 4.8 was released (18 April 2019).

According to [Microsoft's official "What's new in .NET Framework" page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new), .NET Framework 4.8 can be used in Visual Studio 2012 and higher:

> You can target .NET Framework 4.8 in Visual Studio 2012 or later by installing the .NET Framework 4.8 Developer Pack.

Comment: excellent, that is exactly what I was looking for! A reference from MSDN that specifies it's compatible with VS2017